# yii2 - RBAC- permission not added on initialization

Tags: php, yii2

My RbacController.php file is :

```
<?php

namespace common\rbac;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use common\rbac\UserRule;
use common\rbac\IdRule;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        //add "changeDetails" permission
        $changeDetails = $auth->createPermission('changeDetails');
        $changeDetails->description = 'Change Details of all Users';
        $auth->add($changeDetails);

        //add "changeOwnDetails" permission using the rule

        $changeOwnDetails = $auth->createPermission('changeOwnDetails');
        $changeOwnDetails->description = 'Change only personal details';
        $rule = new UserRule;
        $auth->add($rule);
        $changeOwnDetails->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($changeOwnDetails);
        $auth->addChild($changeOwnDetails, $changeDetails);

        //add "changeTheseDetails" permission
        $changeTheseDetails = $auth->createPermission('changeTheseDetails');
        $changeTheseDetails->description = 'Change only personal details';
        $rule2 = new IdRule;
        $auth->add($rule2);
        $changeTheseDetails->ruleName = $rule2->name;
        $auth->add($changeTheseDetails);
        $auth->addChild($changeTheseDetails, $changeOwnDetails);

        //add "user" role
        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $auth->add($user);

        //add "admin" role
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($admin);

        //relate perms and roles
        $auth->addChild($user, $changeOwnDetails);
        $auth->addChild($user, $changeTheseDetails);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $user);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $changeDetails);

    }
}

?>
```

I run this script once by creating 'component' and the database is initialised i.e. the tables 'auth_assignment', 'auth_item', 'auth_item_child' and 'auth_rule' are filled with the specific values but just one permission : 'changeTheseDetails' and rule : 'IdRule' are not added. ( I added these lines of code later i.e. after migration ).
Please Help!!